# Setting Variable to quote and single quote

Tags: c#

As you can see by my code, I am trying to define variables for inch and foot so I can use it in my stringbuilder.

Tried to define the variable as string, char, var not sure what else to do. Also tried the @ to escape.

Any ideas?

```
 var footsize;
    if (dlFtSize.SelectedValue == "in")
    {
        footsize = '\"';
    }
    else if (dlFtSize.SelectedValue == "ft")
    {
        footsize = '\'';
    }
```

EDIT:

Proper way to do it.

```
 string inchsize = "";
    if (dlinchSize.SelectedValue == "In")
    {
        inchsize = "\"";
    }
    else
    {
        inchsize = "'";
    }
```

Comment: Your current code won't compile, but what won't work when you define it as a `char` or `string`? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Changing `var` to `char` should have solved the problem.  What error message or unexpected result do you get?

Comment: The error message should tell you exactly what was wrong.

Comment: When I use char and try to use the variable, I get use of unassigned local variable.

Comment: That's because, as far is the compiler is concerned, dlFtSize.Selected value could be "dfsklj" (or anything else).  Then footsize would have no value associated with it when you try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I use char and try to use the variable, I get use of unassigned local variable.

That's because, as far is the program is concerned, dlFtSize.Selected value could be "dfsklj" (or anything else). Then footsize would have no value associated with it when you try to use it.

You could initialize footsize like this:

```
string footsize = "";
```

Alternatively, you could just use an if/else, rather than an if/else if.

You should be able to use something like:

```
string footsize = "";
if (dlFtSize.SelectedValue == "in")
{
    footsize = "\"";
}
else if (dlFtSize.SelectedValue == "ft")
{
    footsize = "'";
}
```

Using var won't work unless you are assigning a value at the same time.  String is fine, but you have to assign strings to the variable (using double quotes rather than single".  A char should also work, but then you would use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you sir. I started with using a string but I didn't know that the single and double quotes were different. Thought they were both string, didn't know single was char, so I got screwed up.

Answer (score 2):

This is `var footsize;` not valid. You have to assign a value to `footsize` first. Then you can use it. 
([Implicitly Typed Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)).

For instance, var footsize = String.Empty;

Then you also have to change a bit you assignments:

```
if (dlFtSize.SelectedValue == "in")
{
    footsize = "'";
}
else if (dlFtSize.SelectedValue == "ft")
{
    footsize = "\"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the C# ,The single quote is used to define a character literal. The double quote is used to define a string literal. For defining the Inch and Feet, you can use different constant standard  value.

Answer (score 1):

> When I use char and try to use the variable, I get use of unassigned local variable.

You need to make sure you're assigning a value to `footsize`. I would suggest changing your code to the following:

```
char footsize;

switch (dlFtSize.SelectedValue)
{
    case "in":
        footsize = '"';
        break;
    case "ft":
        footsize = '\'';
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("Not implemented foot size: `{0}`", dlFtSize.SelectedValue));
}
```

Also, you can't use `var` without initializing it with a value so that the compiler can tell the type of the variable.